# Organizar informações

Tags: php, array

Tenho um texto como esse:

```
NICK:KEOME PTS:50 ASTS:6 DEFREB:2 OFFREB:7 STLS:14 BLKS:4 TOS:5 NICK:ARTHUR PTS:10 ASTS:3 DEFREB:5 OFFREB:4 STLS:4 BLKS:2 TOS:6
```

Como faço para armazenar as informações mais ou menos desse jeito:

```
Jogadores (
  [nome] => Keome
  [stats] => (
      [pts] => 50
      [asts] => 6
      [dreb] => 2
      [oreb] => 7
      [stls] => 14
      [blks] => 4
      [tos] =>  5
  )
  [nome] => Art
  [stats] => (
      [pts] => 10
      [asts] => 3
      [dreb] => 2
      [oreb] => 1
      [stls] => 4
      [blks] => 5
      [tos] =>  6
  )
)
```

Preciso dos nomes relacionados com as "stats", porém, cada valor separado. Pois preciso jogar esses valores no banco de dados.
Tentei usar esse código mas não obtive sucesso.

```
$linha = 'NICK:KEOME PTS:50 ASTS:6 DEFREB:2 OFFREB:7 STLS:14 BLKS:4 TOS:5 NICK:ARTHUR PTS:10 ASTS:3 DEFREB:5 OFFREB:4 STLS:4 BLKS:2 TOS:6';
  $splitted = explode(" ", $linha);


  $arrN = array(
  );

  foreach ($splitted as $item) {
    $valor = explode(':', $item);
    $arrN[$valor[0]] = $valor[1];
  }
```

Comment: E o que seria o "SAN ANTONIO SPURS"?

Comment: é a equipe, porém uma informação desnecessária.

Comment: E segue um padrão? Como diferenciar o nome do jogador para o nome da equipe?

Comment: na frente do nome do jogador eu posso adicionar um caractere para diferenciar

Comment: Como você gerá este formato? Você já não consegue colocar diretamente no *array* como desejado?

Comment: Eu pego de uma textarea, o problema é que eu não sei como colocar na array, já olhei a documentação porém não entendi muito bem.

Comment: Esses dados chegam ao PHP através de um formulário, então?

Comment: Sim, desse jeito.

Answer (score 3):

Você pode utilizar expressões regulares para extrair os dados:

```
<?php

// Dados de entrada:
$linha = 'NICK:KEOME PTS:50 ASTS:6 DEFREB:2 OFFREB:7 STLS:14 BLKS:4 TOS:5 NICK:ARTHUR PTS:10 ASTS:3 DEFREB:5 OFFREB:4 STLS:4 BLKS:2 TOS:6';

// Verifica se é possível obter os dados com expressão regular:
if (preg_match_all("/([a-zA-Z]+)\:([a-zA-Z0-9]+)\s?/", $linha, $matches)) {

  // Lista de jogadores:
  $players = [];

  // Dados do jogador:
  $player = [];

  // Percorre todos os valores da entrada:
  foreach(array_map(null, $matches[1], $matches[2]) as $pair) {

    // O valor é um nick?
    if (strtoupper($pair[0]) == "NICK") {

      // Se houver dados de outro jogador, adicione a lista:
      if ($player) {
        $players[] = $player;
      }

      // Inicia os dados do jogador para o nick atual:
      $player = ["name" => $pair[1], "stats" => []];

    } else {

      // Não é um nick, então só pode ser um status do jogador atual:
      $player["stats"][strtolower($pair[0])] = $pair[1];
    }
  }

  // Adiciona à lista os dados do último jogador:
  if ($player) {
    $players[] = $player;
  }

  // Exibe a lista de jogadores completa:
  print_r($players);
}
```

> Veja funcionando no [Ideone](http://ideone.com/PjQcHW).

A saída gerada é:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [name] => KEOME
            [stats] => Array
                (
                    [pts] => 50
                    [asts] => 6
                    [defreb] => 2
                    [offreb] => 7
                    [stls] => 14
                    [blks] => 4
                    [tos] => 5
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [name] => ARTHUR
            [stats] => Array
                (
                    [pts] => 10
                    [asts] => 3
                    [defreb] => 5
                    [offreb] => 4
                    [stls] => 4
                    [blks] => 2
                    [tos] => 6
                )

        )

)
```

### Explicação

Com a expressão regular `/([a-zA-Z]+)\:([a-zA-Z0-9]+)\s?/`, obtém-se todos os grupos que seguem o padrão `chave:valor`, isto é, um nome, denominado chave, seguido de dois pontos e um valor. Todos esses valores são agrupados no *array* `$matches`, contendo um índice `1` com todos os nomes e um índice `2` com todos os valores:

```
// print_r($matches);

Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => NICK:KEOME 
            [1] => PTS:50 
            [2] => ASTS:6 
            [3] => DEFREB:2 
            [4] => OFFREB:7 
            [5] => STLS:14 
            [6] => BLKS:4 
            [7] => TOS:5 
            [8] => NICK:ARTHUR 
            [9] => PTS:10 
            [10] => ASTS:3 
            [11] => DEFREB:5 
            [12] => OFFREB:4 
            [13] => STLS:4 
            [14] => BLKS:2 
            [15] => TOS:6
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => NICK
            [1] => PTS
            [2] => ASTS
            [3] => DEFREB
            [4] => OFFREB
            [5] => STLS
            [6] => BLKS
            [7] => TOS
            [8] => NICK
            [9] => PTS
            [10] => ASTS
            [11] => DEFREB
            [12] => OFFREB
            [13] => STLS
            [14] => BLKS
            [15] => TOS
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => KEOME
            [1] => 50
            [2] => 6
            [3] => 2
            [4] => 7
            [5] => 14
            [6] => 4
            [7] => 5
            [8] => ARTHUR
            [9] => 10
            [10] => 3
            [11] => 5
            [12] => 4
            [13] => 4
            [14] => 2
            [15] => 6
        )
)
```

Para agrupar cada chave com seu respectivo valor, utilizamos a função `array_map`.

```
// print_r(array_map(null, $matches[1], $matches[2]));

Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => NICK
            [1] => KEOME
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => PTS
            [1] => 50
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => ASTS
            [1] => 6
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => DEFREB
            [1] => 2
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [0] => OFFREB
            [1] => 7
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [0] => STLS
            [1] => 14
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [0] => BLKS
            [1] => 4
        )

    [7] => Array
        (
            [0] => TOS
            [1] => 5
        )

    [8] => Array
        (
            [0] => NICK
            [1] => ARTHUR
        )

    [9] => Array
        (
            [0] => PTS
            [1] => 10
        )

    [10] => Array
        (
            [0] => ASTS
            [1] => 3
        )

    [11] => Array
        (
            [0] => DEFREB
            [1] => 5
        )

    [12] => Array
        (
            [0] => OFFREB
            [1] => 4
        )

    [13] => Array
        (
            [0] => STLS
            [1] => 4
        )

    [14] => Array
        (
            [0] => BLKS
            [1] => 2
        )

    [15] => Array
        (
            [0] => TOS
            [1] => 6
        )
)
```

Veja que o resultado será uma lista de pares, onde no índice 0 estará o nome e no índice 1 estará o respectivo valor. Após, iteramos sobre esta lista, seguindo a lógica que se encontrado o nome `NICK`, um novo jogador será descrito, ou se for qualquer outro valor, deverá ser considerado como um status do jogador atual.

Comment: Como eu posso adicionar caracteres especiais na expressão regular?

Comment: Até consegue adicionar, mas ela fica gigantesca. É realmente necessário? Se for, provavelmente terá que buscar outra solução.

Comment: Seriam só os caracteres: , ! . e -

Comment: Mas esses são pontuações, não caracteres especiais kkk Tem como dar um exemplo de como eles seriam utilizados e qual seria o resultado esperado?

Comment: Tem jogadores que possuem pontuação no nome, e com essa expressão regular é cortado antes da pontuação, e eu precisaria do nome completo.